# window.history.go(-1) not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

The following line works fine in FireFox, but does nothing in Chrome:

```
<span class='link' onclick='window.history.go(-1);'>Back</span>
```

same thing for the following line:

```
<a class='link' href='#' onclick='window.history.go(-1);return(false);'>Back</a>
```

Viewing the source, the line is highlighted in red and the tooltip for that line says:

"**Token contains a reflected XSS vector**".

So how can I get this to work?

Comment: For me personally its working. Did you try using window.history.back() instead?

Comment: It's working in chrome;

Comment: Oddly enough, when I paste the code in JSFiddle (in Chrome) I don't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `return(false)` write `return false;`
The onclick code should be like

```
onclick="window.history.go(-1);return false;"
```

Comment: Surrounding `false` with brackets is unnecessary, but it's not a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The following anchor tag works for me in Chrome (V49.0.2623.110):

```
<a class='link' href='#' onclick="return window.history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what the problem is. The page is actually generated by a cgi script. One of the parameters this script accepts is text that will be inserted at the top of the page. So the script simply includes this text in its output **as-is**. I included the above line in this parameter and the script simply inserted it at the top of the page. This is of course a **huge** security risk and apparently, Chrome detected this and blocked it.

I'm kind of embarrassed that I needed Chrome to tell me I overlooked such a huge security hole in my cgi script...